# Background Audio in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've got a Xamarin.Forms app.  at one time, I had this working, but alas, something has happened and now it no longer works.  In my Android project, I have  a dependency service as shown below.  I am just trying to play a sound on the local system in the background.  Now, out of the blue, I am getting an error on compile saying that 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Raw'.  I have no idea where this error came from or how to fix it.  There is a directory in Resource folder called raw.  In it, there is a file named flushing.mp3.  the VS intellisense does indicate the file is there. Any ideas are appreciated. TIA

Here is my code for my dependency service:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Audio))]
namespace PooperAppMobile.Droid.DependencyServices
{
    public class Audio : IAudio
    {
        private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;

        public bool PlayFlush()
        {
            _mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.flushing);
            _mediaPlayer.Start();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I went and rebooted my pc and the problem has gone away for the moment.  ugh.

Comment: Hi Does this work I need background playing in my app but I use the media element control in xamrian forms

Answer (score 0):

Well to be quite honest this error was giving me quite a pain when I saw this solution on a GITHUB discussion now all you have to do is add this line in your project file i.e. the .csproj, in your debug property group something like this :

```
<PropertyGroup.......

<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
....

</PropertyGroup>
```

And It will start working as expected,

Good luck!

In case of queries do revert.